# Video Stream Analysis metric

Tags: video-streaming, rtp

Im just new to Video Streaming, and into some video stream deployment. I'm wondering what's the best free analyzer to test RTP streams which can give me bandwidth, jitter etc.

Also what the best metric's to look for when monitoring these streams

I did try VLC, but the bandwidth etc, show as '0'

Answer (score 0):

[VoIP Monitor Sniffer](https://www.voipmonitor.org/) can measure this and logs the output to a MySQL database. It measures PDV, Jitter, calculated MOS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/), it is a free tool.

RTP Stream Analysis: jitter , packet loss
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChTelRTPAnalysis.html

MOS:
PESQ tool (Perceptual evaluation of speech quality (PESQ))

Extract the audio data from the Wireshark and use it in pesq tool.